# Executing commands from a buffer

Tags: shell-command

Following instructions here:-

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecuteExternalCommand

which says:

> Using the whole buffer
> If you are programming using an interpreted language, such as Perl or Python, or a shell script, such as BASH, you might want to run your entire program through the interpreter. To do that, use `C-x h` (`mark-whole-buffer`), then use `M-|` to send all of the buffer text to the interpreter.

As a simple test I created a new buffer which consisted of:

```
mkdir /test
```

then pressed `C-x h` followed by `M-|` but **/test** did not get created.

What am I missing?

Comment: `M-|` is bound to shell-command-on-region, which pipes the region selected through the shell command given in the mini-buffer. Your region text is provided on stdin of the shell command and stdout is shown on the mini buffer. The region and is being replaced by stdout of the shell command if you use the prefix argumanet like `C-U M-|`.

Comment: E.g. try entering `wc` as the shell command, and you'll get the idea.

Comment: I can't get C-U M-| to work. Can I bind a Fn key to such a function?

Comment: Should I enter **wc** in a buffer then 'C-x h' then 'C-U M-|' ?

That doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: If you type a sentence in the buffer, select that text and press `control-u` `alt-|` the minibuffer prompts you for the command. Using `wc` would replace the text with the number of words in that sentence. (Note that windows doesn ot have a `wc` command by default, and that you might need to use `alt-shift-|` because on most keyboards the `|` is above the `\\` key.

Comment: Note there's a typo in the earlier comment.  Should be `C-u` rather than `C-U`.  No shift key.  And if you omit that and just use `M-|` you'll get the results in a separate buffer (or in the echo area for small outputs).

Comment: And for clarity in case you're still confused, none of this is for interpreting the contents of the buffer as shell commands.

Comment: Well, you can if you pipe the contents of the buffer into the shell itself, e,g. with the `mkdir` example, `C-x h M-| bash RET`.

Comment: I think I'm missing how this is supposed to work. All I want to do is pipe a shell script in a buffer into '/bin/sh' . I'm using FreeBSD and don't have bash, but don't think that should make any difference

Comment: NickD's comment is what you want, then.  In your case you would specify `sh` rather than `bash` at the prompt.  `M-| sh RET` is then equivalent to saving the marked region to a file and running `cat <file> | sh` from an interactive shell.  (Hence the mnemonic usage of the character `|` in the key binding, btw.)

Comment: Many thanks @phils, I have it working now, although I'd prefer to automate the process so that 'sh RET' was invoked automatically by having a function key perform  ~C-x h M-| sh RET~. Is this doable?

Comment: `C-h k M-|` documents the function which is being called.  Do some reading about how to create an *interactive function* (command) in elisp and how to bind that to a key/sequence, and use the function shown in the documentation.  See `C-h f point-min` and `point-max` for what to use for the start and end arguments.  Have fun!